# keyframes не работает в Safari

Tags: html, css, css-animation, safari, keyframes

В Хроме и на локальном сервере в Сафари все работает нормально, но когда выгружаю сайт на хостинг в Сафари анимация появляется кусками и лагает.

Отдельно кусок с анимацией:

[Ссылка на CodePen](https://codepen.io/oleg-z-zin/pen/zYrLrMJ)

сейчас норм работает в Сафари, а вот сайт, который выгружаю на хостинг и где анимация лагает:

[Ссылка на сайт](http://qamos.ru/product/)

Что не так? Как это поправить?

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.header-product {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

@keyframes draw_arrow {
  0% {
    width: 1px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}

.has-conte {
  z-index: 500;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 1140px;
}

.img-absf {
  animation: 2s ease-out forwards draw_arrow;
  z-index: 200;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-abss {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-product">
  <div class="has-conte wow fadeInRight animated" data-wow-duration="2s">
    <div class="img-absf">
      <img class="img-abss" data-wow-delay="2.7s" src="https://qamos.ru/product/img/_src/product.svg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-product_img fadeInUp animated" data-wow-duration="2s" style="visibility: visible;-webkit-animation-duration: 2s; -moz-animation-duration: 2s; animation-duration: 2s;">
    <img src="https://qamos.ru/product/img/_src/img11.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: На 13.1.1 все плавно.

Answer (score 0):

Вам следует использовать [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) вместо `left`, `right`, `top`, и `bottom`.

```
transform: translateX(100px) // подвинет объект на 100px вправо
transform: translateY(20px) // подвинет на 20px вниз
transform: translate(20px, 20px) // подвинет на 20px вправо и на 20px вниз
```

Это даст вам возможность анимировать супер-плавно, задействуя GPU и субпиксельные величины.